# How to check same value is matching to how many Ids using MySQL or R

Tags: mysql, r, dataframe, dplyr

I have below-mentioned table in MySQL/Dataframe (MySQL Version - 5.7.18):

Table_1:

```
ID      Date                  uid
I-1     2020-01-01 10:12:15   K-1
I-2     2020-01-02 10:12:15   K-1
I-3     2020-02-01 10:12:15   K-2
I-4     2020-02-02 10:12:15   K-3
I-5     2020-02-04 10:12:15   K-4
I-6     2019-11-01 10:12:15   K-4
I-7     2019-11-01 10:12:15   K-3
I-8     2018-12-13 10:12:15   K-5
I-9     2019-05-17 10:12:15   K-4
I-19    2020-03-11 10:12:15   K-7
```

Table_2:

```
 ID        city           code
I-1        New York       123
I-2        Washington     122
I-3        Tokyo          123
I-4        London         144
I-5        Dubai          101
I-6        Dubai          101
I-7        London         144
I-8        Tokyo          143
I-9        Dubai          101
I-19       Dubai          150
```

Using the above-mentioned table, I want to fetch records between 1st Jan 2020 to 29th Feb 2002 and compare those `ID` in entire database to check whether both `city` and `code` together match with other `ID` and categorize it further to check how many have the same uid and how many have different.

Where,

1. Match - combination of `city` and `code` match with other `ID` in database
2. Same_uid - classification of `Match` ids to identify how many `ID` have similar uid
3. different_uid - classification of `Match` ids to identify how many `ID` doesn't have similar uid
4. uid_count - count of similar uid of that particular `ID` in entire database

Required Output

```
ID      Date                  city         code   uid   Match   Same_uid   different_uid  uid_count
I-1     2020-01-01 10:12:15   New York     123    K-1    No      0          0              2
I-2     2020-01-02 10:12:15   Washington   122    K-1    No      0          0              2
I-3     2020-02-01 10:12:15   Tokyo        123    K-2    No      0          0              1   
I-4     2020-02-02 10:12:15   London       144    K-3    Yes     1          0              2
I-5     2020-02-04 10:12:15   Dubai        101    K-4    Yes     2          0              3
```

Comment: Why is there an R-tag to this? Are you looking for the query? Or are you loading it in R and looking for an R solution?

Comment: Please explain all additional column values detailed, with reference to the values (for example for `Dubai` row). PS. `Match` column is clear - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0be50730944242fe34806b374cd86180).

Comment: @Sotos: R solution will also work, because I have tried it in MySQL but couldn't get the required ouptup.

Comment: @Akina : It was a typo error.

Comment: Well, `uid_count` is clear too. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=26cd95ae045573a6527fc13631efe522). Now explain `Same_uid` and `different_uid` calculation algorhytm.

Comment: @Akina: For Example, `I-5` match with 4 differenct `ID` where in 3 ID we have same uid as `I-5` and in 1 it is different.

Comment: *For Example, I-5 match with 4 differenct ID* Wait... in `Match` we look by (city,code), but there we look by (city) only, is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219186/discussion-between-sophia-wilson-and-akina).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems (after all corrections) that you need

```sql
SELECT t1.ID, 
       t1.`Date`, 
       t1. city, 
       t1.code, 
       t1.uid, 
       CASE WHEN SUM((t1.city = t2.city) * (t1.code = t2.code)) - 1
            THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No' END `Match`,
       SUM((t1.city = t2.city) * (t1.code = t2.code) * (t1.uid = t2.uid)) - 1 same_uid,
       SUM((t1.city = t2.city) * (t1.code = t2.code) * (t1.uid != t2.uid)) different_uid,
       SUM(t1.uid = t2.uid) uid_count
FROM cities t1
CROSS JOIN cities t2
WHERE t1.`Date` >= '2020-01-01' AND t1.`Date` < '2020-03-01'
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.`Date`, t1. city, t1.code, t1.uid
ORDER BY t1.ID
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=47e0b36ed52ccbad9dd84052e16b1f1d)

PS. Multilpyings in `SUM()`s may be replaced with `AND`.

---

> what if I have these information in two different table

```sql
SELECT t11.ID, 
       t11.`Date`, 
       t21.city, 
       t21.code, 
       t11.uid, 
       CASE WHEN SUM((t21.city = t22.city) * (t21.code = t22.code)) - 1
            THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No' END `Match`,
       SUM((t21.city = t22.city) * (t21.code = t22.code) * (t11.uid = t12.uid)) - 1 same_uid,
       SUM((t21.city = t22.city) * (t21.code = t22.code) * (t11.uid != t12.uid)) different_uid,
       SUM(t11.uid = t12.uid) uid_count
FROM /* cities t1 */
     (Table_1 t11 NATURAL JOIN Table_2 t21)
CROSS JOIN /* cities t2 */
           (Table_1 t12 NATURAL JOIN Table_2 t22)
WHERE t11.`Date` >= '2020-01-01' AND t11.`Date` < '2020-03-01'
GROUP BY t11.ID, t11.`Date`, t21.city, t21.code, t11.uid
ORDER BY t11.ID
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9b077e66acf129b26bf3fe2041469f12)

Comment: @Akrina: How can I run this query by joining two tables?

Comment: @SophiaWilson Where do you see two **tables**? there is two **copies** of the same table. Have you looking at the fiddle? there is **one** table in it.

Comment: agreed, but what if I have these information in two different table....I have tried `From table_1 t1 left join table_2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID cross join table_1 t11 and table_2 t22 on t11.ID = t22.ID` but it didn't work.

Comment: @SophiaWilson 1) Not LEFT JOIN but INNER JOIN. 2) EACH table copy in a query must be replaced with your tables pair properly joined (so final query's FROM will refer to 2*2=4 table copies).

Comment: @Akrina: It seems bit complex, let me try ;)

Comment: @SophiaWilson Add new tables DDLs and data into the fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219199/discussion-between-sophia-wilson-and-akina).